# EF6 Code First. ASP Identity security in different database

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, multiple-databases, asp.net-identity-2

I have to have my security in a different database, because multiple applications use the same security database.

I want to be able in one of my models in a project to reference a user virtually. I can't do this however, since it would create a foreign key relationship over different databases, which is impossible.

I also have a common configuration database where several applications use the same config tables, and have the same problem for the same reason.

What's my best move in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I've been asking myself a similar question; not being able to have foreign keys to tables in a different database is problematic.  The best/only solution so far seems to be to just create a field that is a foreign key, but is not set as a FK.  And then manually join using it when necessary.